# Android & Kotlin Coroutines: Is it possible to run out of threads?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, coroutine

How to find out if I am running out of threads in Android/Kotlin?
I am building an app where I need to load a lot of data from a remote API. I add logs in my code to check for a thread name and I see at least 5 Workers running in parallel. The app has swipe-to-refresh feature and if I swipe too much, after a certain amount of calls I lose data somehow (although I do not get Error response from the server). I observe that the call I am interested starts at one worker and then this worker gets occupied by another process. Then the method never completes. I am a bit puzzled. Please help with any suggestions how to resolve the multi-threading issues. Changing `Dispatcher.IO` to the `Dispatcher.Default` does not have any big difference in behavior.
I can put all network calls one after another (in a sequential manner) - then I never lose any data even if I swipe to refresh 100 times. But then all calls are made on the same worker thread and I do not take advantage of parallelism. :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR: Is it possible to run out of threads when using coroutines?** Well, the answer is no (deadlocks are another issue). But, is it possible to use coroutines in a way which means that your concurrency is bound by your number of threads? Yes.

I think the first thing you must understand is the difference between a blocking and non-blocking/suspending/async function.

A real suspending/non-blocking/async function which has some long running functionality, but properly yields control of execution until that long running task is complete is how you really leverage the concurrency that you get with coroutines. Let me demonstrate.

**Muliple coroutines with an internal long running suspending function on 1 thread**

```
val singleThread = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1).asCoroutineDispatcher()

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val jobs = List(10) {
        launch (singleThread){
            delay(1000)
            print(".")
        }
    }
    jobs.forEach { it.join() }
    val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println()
    println(end-start)
}
```

Here we have 10 coroutines that have been launched in quick succession on 1 thread. They all use the suspending function `delay` to simulate a long running task that takes 1000 milliseconds. But... the whole thing finishes in 1018 milliseconds. This will be a bit strange for someone familiar with pure thread based concurrency. Explanation to come. But just to make it absolutely clear, here is the same code, but using `Thread.sleep` instead of `delay`.

**Multiple coroutines on 1 thread with internal long running blocking function**

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val jobs = List(10) {
        launch (singleThread){
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            print(".")
        }
    }
    jobs.forEach { it.join() }
    val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println()
    println(end-start)
}
```

This same bit of code, but with a blocking `Thread.sleep` took 10027 milliseconds. Each coroutine blocked the thread it was on, and so, our 10 coroutines actually executed in series. Control was not given back to the dispatcher while the long running function was being executed.

You can read a much more detail explanation of the difference between non-blocking suspension and blocking calls from Roman Elizarov [here](https://medium.com/@elizarov/blocking-threads-suspending-coroutines-d33e11bf4761)

In your case, I suspect that you are doing your retrieval of data using a blocking IO library. That means that each of those calls is blocking the thread it is on, and not yielding control to the dispatcher while the IO task is completing.

My recommendation would be:

- Carry on using Dispatchers.IO
- Start using a non blocking library to retrieve your data. I recommend [ktor http client](https://ktor.io/clients/http-client.html) with the CIO engine.

**But what about your data loss when you do things concurrently?**

There is not enough information here to be sure, but, I think that you have not built your logic in a way that accounts for concurrency. In a truly parallel execution, swipe number 3 might complete before swipe 2 or swipe 1 completes. If your updates are not idempotent or you are delivering some partial set of data with each update request, then you could be processing update 3 before the others and ignoring update 1 and 2 when they do eventually arrive.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! One part of the problem that the Dispatchers.IO was starting a chain of methods and not all of them were `suspend`. I fixed that. But the real problem was that project is using `Semaphore` library and one last thread was getting stuck in the `synchronized` block. I am not sure why `Semaphore` was added to this project (before me), but after removing it all calls always complete. Puzzled :D again.

Comment: Finally I found the root cause - `synchronized` block was used of a shared HashMap  only when writing and not when removing values.

Comment: @Angelina ah, ya, that could cause issues obviously. Just as a pointer - if you are going to have shared mutable state and you want to use coroutine concurrency, it might be worth encapsulating that shared mutable state in an actor, and achieving thread safety through channel communications -> https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html